# Paginate IEnumerable<T> sequence

Tags: c#, functional-programming, linq, iterator

I used the following to split sequence into batches:

```
source
    .Select((item, index) => new {Item = item, Index = index})
    .ToLookup(x => x.Index / batchSize, x => x.Item);
```

but it requires full materialization of the sequence - memory complexity could be high.

Are there anything ready to be used? I think there is nothing in `MoreLinq` for that.

Here is a custom solution I am trying now:

```
public static class Batch
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
    {
        var it = source.GetEnumerator();
        for (var b = split(); b.Length > 0; b = split())
            yield return b;

        T[] split() => Enumerable
            .Range(0, batchSize)
            .TakeWhile(i => it.MoveNext())
            .Select(i => it.Current)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like what you want, and there are some pretty simple answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258162/linq-how-to-group-by-maximum-number-of-items

Comment: @410_Gone `GroupBy` will make full sequence being materialized before going to the next group - it will try to find everything potentially matching the very first one. I would like to read no more than necessary from the source sequence to reduce memory complexity.

Comment: Doh, silly me. Nevermind.

Comment: @DmitryNogin morelinq Batch is what would be equivalent.  It's not IEnumerable of an array it's IEnumerable of an IEnumerable but if you look at the source code it's actually an IEnumerable of an array https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs

Comment: If you keeping yours you should put GetEnumerable should be put in a using statement.

Comment: @CharlesNRice could you please post an answer? I will upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned morelinq in your question.  It does have the Batch method which is similar.  It's an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>` instead of `IEnumerable<TSource[]>` but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) it's actually an IEnumerable of an array but you can't count on that as it's an implementation detail.

The only issue I see with your implementation is that `source.GetEnumerator()` returns back `IEnumerator<T>` which implements `IDisposable` and should be wrapped in a `using` statement.